# BSOD (Kernel Security Check Failure) when using TAPI in OpenCV 3.1.0 x64 (VS12)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, nvidia, bsod

I am having some issues when using OpenCV 3.1.0 (x64) in Visual Studio 2013. Concretely, a Blue Screen with a Kernel Security Check message shows up when I try to use the TAPI. Just reading a simple cv::UMat crashes everything, if I don't use the TAPI (i.e. using classic cv::Mat) everything runs well. I am guessing if it has to be with the GPU. I've got a NVIDIA GTX970m.

Do you know where the problem could be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution, it was a GPU driver problem. The new version fixed this problem. Just need to update from 361.43 to 361.91.